# Show that the sum of the a function taking a positive and negative input results in an even function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose that $f$ is a function with the property that whenever $x$ is in the domain
of $f$, so is $−x$. 
Show that the function $g(x) = f(x) + f(−x)$ is an even function.

If im honest I dont really know where to start!

Comment: Well, what is $g(-x)$?

Comment: Since its an even function g(-x) must be equal to g(x), but I cant assume that as it is a proof right?

Comment: You have a definition for $g$!  Just plug $-x$ into that.

Comment: Oh sorry i didnt really understand what the question was asking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To show that a function $f$ is even, all you need do is compute $f(-x)$ and observe whether $$f(-x)=f(x).$$ If this happens, then $f$ is even. Otherwise it is not.